# How to log spring websocket packets?

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I have a simple websocket controller:

```
    @MessageMapping("/v1/send")
    @SendToUser(destinations = "/topic/history", broadcast = false)
    public String send(@Valid MessageRequest message, Principal principal) {
        String userId = principal.getName();
        updateMdcAndInfo(String.format("SEND: %s", message), userId, Constants.METHOD_SEND_MESSAGE);

        simpleMessageTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(userId, Topic.MESSAGES.getTopic(), Collections.singletonList(message));

        return "foo";
    }
```

I want to log all inbound\outbound messages. Implemented **ChannelInterceptor** with methods **postSend**, **postReceive** but only inboundChannel messages are logged.

How can I log both inboundChannel\OutboundChannel messages ?